# How to divide my script output by the output of another command?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a folder, `my_folder`, which contains over 800 files named `myfile_*.dat` where * is the unique ID for each file. In my file I basically have a variety of repeated fields but the one I am interested in is the `<rating>` field. Lines of this field look like the following: `<rating>n` where n is the rating score. I have a script which sums up all of the ratings per file, but now I must divide it by the number of lines that have `<rating>n` in order to obtain an average rating per file. Here is my script:

```
dir=$1
cd $dir
grep -P -o '(?<=<rating>).*' * |awk -F: '{A[$1]+=$2;next}END{for(i in A){print i,A[i]}}'|sort -nr -k2
```

I figure that I would use `grep -c <rating> myfile_*.dat` to count the number of matching lines and then divide the sum by this count per file but do not know where to put this in my script? Any suggestions are appreciated.

My script takes the folder name as an argument in the command line.

**INPUT FILE**

```
<Overall Rating>
<Avg. Price>$155
<URL>

<Author>Jeter5
<Content>I hope we're not disappointed! We enjoyed New Orleans...
<Date>Dec 19, 2008
<No. Reader>-1
<No. Helpful>-1
<rating>4
<Value>-1
<Rooms>3
<Location>5
<Cleanliness>3
<Check in / front desk>5
<Service>5
<Business service>5

<Author>...
repeat fields again...
```

Comment: The output should be myfile_* where * is the unique ID per file followed by the average rating.

Comment: Look at `awk` `NR` for the total number of rows - would having that allow for the average you need? Adding `A[i]/NR` in your `END` statement?

Comment: Not every row is rating field row though, there are many other rows , it needs to be the number of rows where <rating> appears to give an average

Comment: Could I just assign my suggested command to a variable and then divide A[i] by that, for example count=$(grep -c rating myfile_*.dat) then A[i]/count?

Comment: Oh, I see, you have the per-file average, but now you need the average over all files. Why not add your `grep -c` as a line before your per-file call and assign the count to a variable and pass that to `awk`. e.g. `count=$(grep -c '<rating>' myfile_*.dat)`.

Comment: No I am trying to get the per file average, I will post my input file to make it clearer.

Comment: So my script sums up (per file) the value after the <rating> field but now I need to divide that by the number of <rating> fields there are to get an average

Comment: I am ignorant to whether awk is capable of what you are are attempting and you may have to process your files sequentially (in a loop file by file) in order to perform this type of operation. If this is an acceptable option and I will post an answer.

Comment: So rewrite my script in a loop format? Yes that makes sense

Comment: @JohnSmith Yes that is the approach I would take.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin problem was that his `grep` command does all the files at once, so if there were 300 ratings in 50 files, `NR` would be 300.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set up another array `L` to track the count of items:

```
grep -P -o '(?<=<rating>).*' * |
awk -F: '{A[$1]+=$2;L[$1]++;next}END{for(i in A){print i,A[i],A[i]/L[i]}}' |
sort -nr -k2
```

Comment: thanks, does this give the average rating per file or for the folder?

Comment: `L` is indexed by file, just like `A` is, so will be per-file.

Comment: Sorry, how would I remove the .dat file extension from my output when I print out the file name?